# Accessing Element In linkedList

Tags: java, collections

```
LinkedList<String> linkedList = new LinkedList<>();

linkedList.add("Java");
linkedList.add("Python");
linkedList.get(1);
```

Internal code flows for get

```
public E get(int index) {
    checkElementIndex(index);
    return node(index).item;
}

private void checkElementIndex(int index) {
     if (!isElementIndex(index))
     throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(outOfBoundsMsg(index));
}
```

I am calling, linkedList.get(1); to get the second element in an linked list. My question is, uf LinkedList internally created nodes for each element, then how does an indexing concept come into consideration for accessing the element (`linkedList.get(1)`)?

Comment: If you check the `node(int)` implementation in that same class you have your answer. It will start at either the first node, or last node (depending on if the index you're looking for is closer to the start or to the end) and then it loops until it finds the index you are requesting.

Comment: Does that means, Linked List internally uses Array concept ?

Comment: No, it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This index is not like the array index in `ArrayList`
.
In a `LinkedList`, the get by index method under the hood is just a **for loop**, and since the list is ordered, it will simply return the element you need by looping through elements of the list.

Look inside `LinkedList` for the `Node<E> node(int index)` method, which is called in the `get(int index)` method.

Comment: Thank you very much  Georgii Lvov!! It really helped me understanding internal mechanism -